# Ionic - Append objects to array in $localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-storage

I've tried to follow examples here, I know there might be a few different ways of adding objects to an array in $localstorage and not overwriting it but I'm failing to find at least one of them.

**

> TypeError: $scope.sTempLoc.push is not a function

**

```
.controller('AddWfhCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $localStorage, $ionicLoading, $ionicHistory, $cordovaGeolocation,$ionicPopup, focus){
  $scope.saveWfhLocation = function (){
        $scope.sTempLoc = [];
        if(typeof $scope.uCurLocDtls.uCuWfhLocName != "undefined" || $scope.uCurLocDtls.uCuWfhLocName != ""){
            if(angular.isDefined($localStorage.userWFHLocs)){
                $scope.sTempLoc = $localStorage.userWFHLocs;
                $scope.sTempLoc.push($scope.uCurLocDtls);
                $localStorage.userWFHLocs = $scope.sTempLoc;
            }else{
                $localStorage.userWFHLocs = $scope.uCurLocDtls;
            }
            $ionicHistory.goBack();
        }

    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you give $localForage a try because I think it is better and easier to work with than $localStorage.

Reference: https://github.com/localForage/localForage